# Simplest way to stub a JMS message?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jms, message-driven-bean

I'd like to unit test a Java EE `Message Driven Bean`'s `onMessage()` method. It receives a JMS message and does reading and some processing of the message content.

I'd like to stub the JMS message, but both ways known to me are not optimal:

- Using a mocking framework (e.g. Mockito), I have to stub quite some method calls, which results in unreadable tests.
- Implementing the `javax.jms.Message` inteface for a manual stub message means I need to implement like "a hundred" methods, most of which I don't need. That looks ugly to me...

Is there a better way that I could use? I've heard that Spring has a good JMS Facade, but I'm not using Spring.

Comment: I'd still suggest going with Mockito's mock. As I see it, there are 2 ways to go about it - use a lib/framework that already did the mocking for you, OR do the mocking yourself. Any given day, I'd choose the former since it's fairly straightforward to mock an object. Not sure what you mean by 'not readable' though. If you can extract the mocking piece into an external method, code should be quite clean.

Comment: What I meant by not readable: for example I have to stub out the `BytesMessage#readBytes` method. If you look up the API, it expects a byte Array that will be then filled. That means I have to use some kind of `Answer` mechanism with the mock... I can't use a simple `when(...).thenReturn`.